# How to implement the trained Tensorflow model for my pictures?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, model

I am studying the Tensorflow classification from textbook and compiled the following code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

def train_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, learning_rate, max_epochs,batch_size):
in_X_tensors_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, RESIZED_IMAGE[0],RESIZED_IMAGE[0],1))
in_y_tensors_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, N_CLASSES))
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
logits=model(in_X_tensors_batch, is_training)
out_y_pred=tf.nn.softmax(logits)
loss_score=tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=in_y_tensors_batch)
loss=tf.reduce_mean(loss_score)
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(max_epochs):
        print("Epoch=", epoch)
        tf_score = []
        for mb in minibatcher(X_train,y_train,batch_size,shuffle=True):
            tf_output=session.run([optimizer,loss],
                                 feed_dict = {in_X_tensors_batch:mb[0],
                                             in_y_tensors_batch:mb[1],
                                             is_training:True})
            tf_score.append(tf_output[1])
        print("train_loss_score=",np.mean(tf_score))
    print("TEST SET PERFORMANCE")
    y_test_pred, test_loss = session.run([out_y_pred,loss],
                                        feed_dict={in_X_tensors_batch:X_test,
                                                  in_y_tensors_batch:y_test,
                                                  is_training:False}) 
    print("test_loss_score=",test_loss)
    y_test_pred_classified = np.argmax(y_test_pred,axis=1).astype(np.int32)
    y_test_true_classified = np.argmax(y_test,axis=1).astype(np.int32)
    print(classification_report(y_test_true_classified,y_test_pred_classified))
    cm=confusion_matrix(y_test_true_classified,y_test_pred_classified)
    plt.imshow(cm,interpolation='nearest',cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    plt.imshow(np.log2(cm+1),interpolation='nearest',cmap=plt.get_cmap("tab20"))
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Now I am curious, how to use this model for my own pictures to check how it works. This code was was used to convert image to numerical form, how should I handle my own pictures?

[image]

Comment: Hey, I know this is not the answer to your question. But, I will recommend you use a more recent textbook. The TF code you have shown is TF1.x style and the currently popular version is TF2.x and it's far easier to work with and also has more examples/tutorials/books etc.

Comment: Hello. I know, the textbook is from 2018 and i had to downgrade my TF for it to work.